# Spring MVC: Any way to get generated html file before you send it to client?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Is there any way using Spring MVC to get the generated html file (from it's original jsp)?

See comments below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/index")
public class Router {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String details(..., ModelMap model) throws ApplicationServiceException {
        //add attribute to model, change generated html from base jsp
        model.addAttribute("test", "test");
        //instead of returning index.jsp (like below) ...
        return "index";
        //...is it possible to get index.jsp (as it's generated html file) like such:
        File html = new File("index.html");
    }

}
```

index.jsp:

```
<html>
${test}
</html>
```

(generated) index.html: <- the file I want

```
<html>
test
</html>
```

Please let me know if my description is not clear, english is not my first language so I'll try to explain better. Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by doing this? HTML needs lot of other things like css, javascripts etc, so why you are not deploying your code in your local server and see whats getting generated?

Comment: Why would you need this? Let the view resolver do its work.

Comment: I'm going to send the html file to the client alongside all the necessary js, css files in a zip. Hence why I need it as a File. @AmitKBist I can deploy it to my local server, and I have, but that's not how I want it to work

Comment: is the client not a browser? - I am trying to understand the use case here

Comment: @ochi hi, yes, that's what I meant by 'client' (the browser).. i think that's the correct terminology. Anyway, the use case here is to send a generated html inside a zip file (so the client wouldn't open the page in the browser, but instead download it inseide a zip file).

Comment: I see, then use a templating engine... imo it's a better solution

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't know about templating engines. If you make this as an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "get the generated html file".

If you add a filter to the web.xml file,
the filter will see the response before it is sent to the user and after exiting the handler (and after "conversion" from JSP to html).

Edit: Circumvent

If you wrap the response object in a class of your own (in the filter),
you can then change the response (again, in the filter) after the handler.

Comment: I have numerous filters in web.xml, is there any way to circumvent the html file after it exits the filter, but before it gets sent to the client? Or alternatively, is it possible to bypass the handler entirely and just generate a html file from a jsp using a new model?

Comment: There should be no reason to "generate an html file from a jsp using a new model" in the filter.  Just pass the correct model from the handler.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a small code snippet to explain what you mean? I'm fairly new to spring, perhaps I misunderstood the functionality of the model. To be clear- I don't want to pass the jsp/html directly to the client's browser.

Comment: "I don't want to pass html directly to the client's browser" makes no sense what-so-ever.  Explain that.

Comment: Sorry. I mean I want to use the html elsewhere in my handler (rather than return it). In my case, I want to add it to a zip file, and return this zip from the handler.